# Chosen plugin is not working when i add dynamically selectbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

When I dynamically add a row the Chosen plugin doesn't work on new selectboxes. How can I add the Chosen functionality to new selectboxes?

```js
var sayac = 6;
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.addd', function(){
  var html = '';
  sayac += 1;
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><select name="kagit_tip[]" class="select form-control inst_amount' + sayac + '"><option value="">Kağıt Tipi</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="kagit_ebat[]" class="select form-control inst_amount' + sayac + '"><option value="">Kağıt Ebadı</option><?php echo kagit_ebat_selectbox($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="tabaka[]" class="form-control item_quantity inst_amount' + sayac + '" " /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="kgfiyati[]" class="form-control item_quantity inst_amount' + sayac + '" " /></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';  
  $('#item_table').append(html);
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
      <span id="error"></span>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
        <tr>
          <th>Ek Kağıt</th>
          <th>Ebat</th>
          <th>Tabaka</th>
          <th>Kg Fiyatı</th>
          <th>Ek Kağıt Tutar</th>
          <th><button type="button" name="addd" class="btn btn-success btn-sm addd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're calling `chosen()` when the page loads, hence it only works on the `select` elements in the DOM at that point.

To fix your issue you need to call `chosen()` again on the new elements you dynamically added, something like this:

```js
var sayac = 6;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.addd', function() {
    sayac++;

    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td><select name="kagit_tip[]" class="select form-control inst_amount' + sayac + '"><option value="">Kağıt Tipi</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="kagit_ebat[]" class="select form-control inst_amount' + sayac + '"><option value="">Kağıt Ebadı</option><?php echo kagit_ebat_selectbox($connect); ?></select></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="tabaka[]" class="form-control item_quantity inst_amount' + sayac + '" " /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="kgfiyati[]" class="form-control item_quantity inst_amount' + sayac + '" " /></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';

    var $row = $(html).appendTo('#item_table');        
    $row.find('select').chosen({
      // your options here...
    });
  });
});
```

Also note that incremental id/class attributes are an anti-pattern which I would suggest you remove.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. in area " // your options here... " i i add select input's code again? is it true?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but the call to `chosen()` should look the same as the one you make when the page first loads.